# yui treeview checkbox does not expand nodes

Tags: javascript, treeview, yui

I am using YUI TreeView with checkbox. I cannot use YUI3 CheckboxTree as the system is a little old and we use YUI 2.9. I followed the example [YUI TreeView with checknox](http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0/examples/treeview/tv_highlight.html). Basically I created a widget that extends YUI TreeView. I am able to get the checkboxes on my nodes and am able to check them, but the nodes do not expand.

My guess is that the problem can be with the following statement:

`this.subscribe('clickEvent',this.onEventToggleHighlight);`

I tried defining my own onEventToggleHighlight as follows:

```
onEventToggleHighlight: function(oArgs) {
    var node = oArgs.node;
    node.hightlight();
    node.focus();
    node.toggle();
    return false;
}
```

After doing this, I am able to expand the nodes, but checkboxes stop working. Kindly suggest where I am going wrong. I have set the `propagateHighlightUp` and `propagateHighlightDown` node properties to true as well. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in replying, I was out of town.  I think [this](http://satyam.com.ar/yui/#tasklist) might help you.  The example was made in the last days of YUI2 and I think something was missing in the version on the YUI site but nobody at Yahoo was keeping an eye on YUI2 at the time so it slipped through.